# Is It Possible To Backup Settings And All Customized Stuff I Made On Android Cellphone?

Tags: backup, system

Which backup is that? Full backup that backs up **whole system**? Or is it only backup that backs up **settings and customized stuff**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Titanium Backup](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup), it'll fit your needs.

Comment: It needs rooted device.

Comment: there isn't any app which will do all that you have asked for w/o root privileges

Answer (score 1):

If you're rooted and have a ROM that supports Recovery like ClockworkMod, a full Nandroid backup is akin to taking an image/snapshot of your device. When recovering from that image, your phone will be restored to exactly that same state when the backup was taken.

Comment: A bit offtopic, but out of curiousity: do you know if a Nandroid backup can be recovered onto a replacement device or does this mess up the individual device info (IMEI or such)?

Comment: It does mess things up. A Nandroid backup is recommended for one particular device alone. Not even another device that's the same model etc., AFAIK. However, I'm not 100% sure.